# Allowed memory size exhausted after switching PHP from 7.1 to 7.2

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, php, php7

Previously, my site ran on PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. After upgrade, I could still access my site.

Then I [installed](https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/) and [switched](https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/) to PHP 7.2 (I didn't remove PHP 7.1, only disable it). When accessing, it shows a Laravel error about database connection error. Then I enable `mysql` and `pdo_mysql` in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`. After that, my site only returns 500 internal server error.

I checked `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and it says:

`[Tue Dec 17 11:12:36.773684 2019] [php7:error] [pid 27730] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:y] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 31`

The `memory_limit` in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` has been `-1` from the start.

Comment: The file you have changed is used for PHP CLI you need to increase `memory_limit`  in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` file. After that restart apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Try `php --ini` in your command line and it will help you to find loaded configuration file.
Then increase the memory_limit on that file.
After that restart your apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`